# With Lucene, if someone searches for "red barn", how do you also return results that contain "redbarn"?

Tags: lucene, elasticsearch

I have a working search where if someone searches for two separate words (like "red barn", Lucene does a great job of returning records that have "red barn", "barn red", and "red tractor next to the big brown barn". That's great, but the results do not return anything that contains "redbarn" (unless you specifically search for "redbarn", but then you don't get "red barn" records).

I'm just using the standard analyzer at the moment, but am not sure what needs to change in order to get the all records I'd like.

If it matters, I'm using the NEST client on top of ElasticSearch (which is Lucene under the hood). I've researched the various analyzers and properties available but haven't found the right combination to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to do this is to write an analyzer that would tokenize "redbarn" as ["red", "barn"]. Lucene already does it for german languages, you can look at [DictionaryCompoundWordTokenFilter](http://lucene.apache.org/core/3_6_0/api/all/org/apache/lucene/analysis/compound/DictionaryCompoundWordTokenFilter.html) for example.

Comment: here is how to do it in elastic search, http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/index-modules/analysis/compound-word-tokenfilter.html

Answer (score -1):

Standard analyzer works for most cases but if you need detailed text analysis you need to write your own analyzer.

[WorldDelimeterFilter](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/lucene/java/tags/lucene_solr_3_4_0/solr/core/src/java/org/apache/solr/analysis/WordDelimiterFilter.java) that comes with Solr should solve your problem. Solr is built on top of lucene so you should not have a problem if you use the filters that come with solr.See the example below:

```
public class CustomAnalyzer extends Analyzer { 
  public TokenStream tokenStream(String fieldName, Reader reader) { 
    TokenStream ts = new WhitespaceTokenizer(reader); 
    ts = new WordDelimiterFilter(ts, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1); 
    ts = new LowerCaseFilter(ts); 
    return ts; 
  } 
}
```

Comment: The OP specifically asks how to accomplish this using ElasticSearch.